# Button color not changing in android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

So I just went into attributes in android studio to change the color of the button, just like I would the name of the button and other attributes. But now the color seems not to be taking effect when I compile and run on my phone.
I can only see the color change when I change the theme view but, I can not see it when I compile and send to phone.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_answer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FA39D328"
            android:backgroundTint="#E10A0A"
            android:text="Button" />
```

[This is the only options i have with theme, I can see the the color only on different themes but they do not show up when  I run the app. Before changing attributes would change the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmz8q.png)

[This is the attributes change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Gau.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove android:background="#FA39D328", use only android:backgroundTint="#E10A0A".

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_answer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#E10A0A"
            android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: That finally worked!!, but why does android:background="#FA39D328" 
not work alone But tint works.

Comment: tutorial I'm following is, but it worked for him.
https://youtu.be/ja1Jli7bHNM?t=478

Comment: android:background is used for implementing drawable backgrounds and tint is used for colors

Comment: And, if you want to use android:background="#FA39D328" for color than you also have to use app:backgroundTintMode="add"

Answer (score 1):

Use AppCompatButton

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/click"
        android:background="#FA39D328"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pay_now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```